# Sql loader NULLIF with TERMINATED BY '\t'

Tags: sql, sql-loader, nullif

i am trying to load my data in my table. My data is terminated by '\t' and when I try:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0)
load data
infile 'C:\*'
APPEND into table Table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
FNAME                    NULLIF NAME=BLANKS,
LNAME                     NULLIF LNAME=BLANKS,
SUFFIX                    NULLIF SUFFIX=BLANKS,
HNAME                    NULLIF HNAME=BLANKS,
ADDRESS1              NULLIF ADDRESS1=BLANKS,
ADDRESS2              NULLIF ADDRESS2=BLANKS,
CITY                         NULLIF CITY=BLANKS,
HSTATE                    NULLIF HSTATE=BLANKS,
ZIP                            NULLIF ZIP=BLANKS,
EXTENDED_ZIP        NULLIF EXTENDED_ZIP=BLANKS,
COUNTRY                 NULLIF COUNTRY=BLANKS,
)
```

I can successfully load my data in my table, but no null value show up and it inserted the next column values instead of (null).

Can anyone help me please

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show what your data looks like after the table load? i see an extra `,` after country column in the file.

Comment: Are you sure there was not a missing TAB in the data file?

Answer (score 0):

```
1) As vkp pointed out , an extra ',' after country name.
2) FNAME                    NULLIF **NAME**=BLANKS
```

it should be 'FNAME'

Try these changes, it works fine for me.